# Constraint layout margins keep changing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

The margins of the left button keep changing as you can see in the video and I would like them to not change.

I am doing a calculator and i want to move all the buttons togheter without changing the margins.

The video is there: https://youtu.be/UT3zINpaMhY

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.a3ibm.calculator.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="86dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.864"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.319" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking please clarify your problem. What is the purpose of this layout? what do you going to acheive using `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: I am doing a calculator and i want to move all the buttons togheter without changing the margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the possible solution you want. The problem was with centering:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="186dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="208dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: By the way dude. If u want the buttons move horizontally, u should center all buttons(by selecting) vertically. Hope it is what you want

Comment: Actually i would have liked to move the buttons freely, as the video shows, but without changing the margins.
Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: because, over there i did what u asked

Comment: With your code I can only move the buttons vertically, not horizontaly

Comment: just a sec I ll try to fix

Comment: When I select and move the two buttons, the space between them keeps changing

Comment: dude, when I move it is not changing

Comment: really, it is not. If you dont believe I can upload video

Comment: can you plz accept answer. because i did what u asked

Comment: As you can see in my version keeps changing:
https://youtu.be/vcaPjxDwXSg
Maybe it's a bug of my Android Studio

Comment: dude, the bug is in your side. Jus delete all chains which are in left and right sides of the buttons. then it is gonna work

Comment: in the code above there is no chains, but stupid android studio adds them when pasted